# How to share a post to a facebook group, not my own timeline, using the Facebook SDK share dialog?

Tags: ios, facebook, dialog, share, facebook-group

I'm trying to share a link object to a Facebook group using the share dialog. No one seems to have answered this question satisfactorily yet.

The SDK documentation clearly states that you can use the share dialog to share to your own timeline or groups, yet I can't figure out how to do it. I also don't see any other apps that do it. Using the web share dialogue on a desktop you can see the option, but on a mobile website you don't! This screenshot of the iOS Facebook app shows what I'm talking about:

[image: screenshot of Facebook on iOS]

I'm trying to get the functionality in where it says 'tap to change' at the top.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have to use an instance of FBSDKShareDialog, and set the mode to FBSDKShareDialogModeNative.

```
FBSDKShareDialog *dialog = [[FBSDKShareDialog alloc] init];
dialog.fromViewController = viewController;

FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
content.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.test.com"];
content.contentTitle = productItem.productTitle;
dialog.shareContent = content;
dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogModeNative;

if (![dialog canShow]) {
    dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogModeWeb;
}

dialog.delegate = self;
[dialog show];
```

Comment: THanks so much for your answer! But for me this produces the UI above without the desired "tap to change" button at the top...Any ideas why?

Comment: I updated the code above, and I'm able to see the "Tap To Change" that allows me to share to a group.

Comment: How to give facebook group path for posting video into facebook group.